# In Back-channel logout, If the logout is invalid, then RP should respond with HTTP 400 Bad request. Then how will the OP handle this?

Tags: logout, openid-connect

In OpenID Connect Back-channel logout, If the logout is invalid, then RP should respond with HTTP 400 Bad request. Then how OP will handle this?

I couldn't find that in the [spec.](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html#BCResponse)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying...
Back-channel logout specifically addresses OP-Initiated Logout request. (RP-Initiated logout requests are in [OpenID Connect Session Management 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html))

In this case the OP has already performed the process of clearing the "session" data and is notifying the RP of the changed condition of the "session".

I can not come up with a possible action of the OP at the failure of the RP to cancel the "session".

I assume since the RP responded with HTTP 400 Bad Request error, that this SHOULD only happen as the RP failed to validate the token.

I guess the OP could keep the RP in the "Remembered Logged-In RPs" list and try the request again. But at some point the OP would have to assume this is just an inability on the part of the RP.

There is also a possibility the OP could re-direct the end-user back to the RP in which case the RP would need to deal with it.

BTW: These are all *drafts* and the bottom of the Drafts show the Authors' Addresses which you can contact to make suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to know whether OP sends a logout token again to that RP?

Comment: I think that would be possible, depending on the OP Implementation; but why? Would we expect the logout token to be different next time? How many time should this be repeated?

Comment: That is what I'm also asking. If OP sends a logout token again, how many times it can repeat? T

Comment: Zero to infinity according to the spec.